# How to match elements in lists in every row with pandas

Tags: pandas, list, for-loop

I have a dataframe with 3 columns. ID, Date and Recommendations. Recommendations is a column of list containing multiple values for each day. I want to find the recommendations that match with day `d` and day `d+1` for every ID. The dataframe looks like below.

```
| ID | Date       | Recommendations |
| 1  | 1/1/2021   | [A, B, C]       |
| 1  | 1/2/2021   | [A, F, C]       |
| 1  | 1/3/2021   | [A, B, D]       |
| 2  | 1/13/2021  | [A, B, C]       |
| 2  | 1/14/2021  | [A, B, C]       |
| 2  | 1/15/2021  | [A, H, C]       |
```

I want the result to look like below

```
| ID | Date       | Recommendations | Match |
| 1  | 1/1/2021   | [A, B, C]       | 2     |
| 1  | 1/2/2021   | [A, F, C]       | 1     |
| 1  | 1/3/2021   | [A, B, D]       | 0     |
| 2  | 1/13/2021  | [A, B, C]       | 3     |
| 2  | 1/14/2021  | [A, B, C]       | 2     |
| 2  | 1/15/2021  | [A, H, C]       | 0     |
```

The calculation should happen at ID level. So all the IDs will have the last value as 0.
The dates may not always be sorted, but i want it sorted before matching the recommendations. Is there an efficient way to do this in python? I have close to 5M rows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ALollz answer is very clever and pythonic. A more "brute force" answer is to shift inside the group to get the next days recommendations for each user, and then simply compare the two columns using the set intersection operator:

```
df["recommendations_next_day"] = df.groupby(by='ID')['Recommendations'].shift(-1)

df["Recommendations"] = df.Recommendations.apply(set)
df["recommendations_next_day"]= df.recommendations_next_day.apply(lambda x: set(x) if x==x else set())
df["count"]= df[["Recommendations","recommendations_next_day"]].apply(lambda x: len(x[0] & x[1]) 
                    ,axis =1)
```

Of course, this assumes DF is sorted by ID, and then date and there are records for each day.

Answer (score 2):

Turn your date column into a `datetime` then `explode` the list.  Then by merging this exploded DataFrame with itself (where we subtract 1 day from the date) we are keeping only rows within the same ID, that have the same recommendation on Date and Date+1day. Taking the size, grouped by the original index, gives use the match column, which we can assign back (as alignment is on the Index)

```
import pandas as pd

df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], format='%m/%d/%Y')

df1 = df.explode('Recommendations').reset_index()
df1 = df1.merge(df1.drop(columns='index').assign(Date=df1['Date']-pd.offsets.DateOffset(days=1)))

df['match'] = df1.groupby('index').size()
df['match'] = df['match'].fillna(0, downcast='infer')
```

---

```
   ID       Date Recommendations  match
0   1 2021-01-01       [A, B, C]      2
1   1 2021-01-02       [A, F, C]      1
2   1 2021-01-03       [A, B, D]      0
3   2 2021-01-13       [A, B, C]      3
4   2 2021-01-14       [A, B, C]      2
5   2 2021-01-15       [A, H, C]      0
```

Comment: This doesn't count the numbers of elements that match in the two lists of day d and d+1. It is a great way but with not the expected answer. Thank you though.

Comment: @SudhakarSamak I don't understand your comment because this solution does **exactly**. If your real data have duplicates in the recommendations list, or is duplicated on [ID, Date] then it might differ from what you expect, but that's because you seem to want a row-to-row comparison, despite specifying next day.

Comment: And to be clear, this explicitly checks subsequent days, the solution you accepted only cares about subsequent rows, regardless of whether there are 1 or 10 days between them (within ID).